# What is the correct way to make multer work with Node and Express here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to create a route through which I can upload photos. However as I made so,e changes it stopped working and I am not sure how to make it work.

```
const multer = require('multer');

// MULTER STORAGE
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, '/upload');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    // Saving format: user-UserId-DateStamp.ext
    //e.g user-608d55c7e512b74ee00791de-1621992912638.jpeg
    cb(null, `user-${req.body.userId}-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
  },
});

//MULTER FILTER
const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  //mimetype always starts with image/ then png or jpeg or..
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new AppError('You are only allowed to upload image files.', 400), false);
  }
};

const uploadDirectory = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter,
});

//exports.uploadPhoto = uploadDirectory.single('photo');

//app.use(express.static('./uploads'));

// INCLUDE ERROR CLASS AND ERROR CONTROLLER
const AppError = require('../utils/appError.js');
const errorController = require('./errorController.js');
const { Mongoose } = require('mongoose');
```

The main problem Im guessing is in this block

```
//UPLOAD PHOTO
exports.uploadPhoto = uploadDirectory(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);

  try {
    const newPhoto = await photoModel.create(req.file);
    newPhoto.save().then((result) => {
      console.log('Saved');
      res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        // data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newPhoto.file)),
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in upload');
    errorController.sendError(err, req, res);
  }
}).single('photo');
```

Can anybody let me know how to correctly write the exports.uploadPhoto

Originally the last function looked like this

```
exports.uploadPhoto = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);

  try {
    const newPhoto = await photoModel.create(req.file);
    newPhoto.save().then((result) => {
      console.log('Saved');
      res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        // data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newPhoto.file)),
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in upload');
    errorController.sendError(err, req, res);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The multer middleware function, in your case `uploadDirectory`, is usually used before other middleware functions/controllers where you have your business logic (e.g. `uploadPhoto`).

```js
app.post('/upload', uploadDirectory.single('photo'), uploadPhoto);
```

Keep your original `uploadPhoto` function and with the above code you'll have access to the data and file through `reg.body` and `req.file`, respectively.

This [Request Parsing in Node.js Guide](https://maximorlov.com/request-parsing-nodejs-guide/) (it's free) will help you with file uploads in Node.js.

Comment: I did that and I can now actually save to my database, however my photos are no longer being saved in my local drectory

Comment: Try changing the destination from `/upload` to `upload` and see if it works. The first might save at the root of your laptop/server, second saves at the root of your project instead.